# Changing the colour of a cell depending on the value of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

If the tick box in column G is true I need to change the colour of the columns I and J of that row to a Dark Grey. If the tick box is false I need to change the colour of the columns M,N,O & P to Dark Grey.

[Conditional Formatting Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBVVq.png)

This level of conditional formatting is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please select ColumnsI:J and try: Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=$G1=true
```

and then select ColumnsM:P and:

```
=$G1=false
```

each with Dark Grey format.

(Will format blank rows also.)